# Quarkus JsonB change to different timezone

Tags: java, jsonb, quarkus, yasson

quarkus jsonb is deserializing json in UTC. How can I configure a different timezone?

```
public class AtendimentoDTO {
    public Integer id;

    @JsonbDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private Date dataAtualizacao;
}
```

Output in UTC:

```
"dataAtualizacao": "23/05/2020 21:55:57"
```

maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix it by changing the provider to `jackson` and using:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, 
  pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", timezone = "GMT-3")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this date format:

```
@JsonbDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z")
```

And afaik, LocalDateTime doesn't support timezones. You need to use ZonedDateTime but I am not sure whether this works out-of-the-box with JsonB, otherwise you need to write a Serializer & Deserializer for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LocalDateTime` instead of `Date`. LocalDateTime will take the default system time-zone, while `Date` will be using UTC timezone by default.